# how to extract Regular expression extractor from jmeter response?

Tags: regex, jmeter

`ChemicalID=265297\u0026RptId=46160`.

This is a text from my jmeter request response. Can somebody help me how to write regular expression to extract `265297` from the above response?

Comment: ChemicalID=(.+?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Regular Expression:

```
ChemicalID=(\d+)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Demo]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Regular expressions in Perl](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) (JMeter uses Perl5-style regular expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ChemicalID=(?<chemicalId>\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sKteQF/1)

Comment: org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: ChemicalID=(?<chemicalId>\d+)
Sequence (?<...) not recognized.Chemical ID is dynamic too

Comment: Oh! Looks like the regex engine you are using does not support named groups. Then, just use this pattern - `ChemicalID=(\d+)`.